# SQL - Create Temp tables with IF THEN ELSE

Tags: sql, if-statement

I am trying to write a SQL query where the if output is 'FRUIT' a temp table 'FRUIT' is created with a column 'FOOD_TYPE' and if not, then a temp table 'VEGETABLE' is created with a column 'FOOD_TYPE'.

Here is the initial query I wrote.

```
select *,
(CASE 
WHEN food LIKE 'APPLE'
THEN 'FRUIT' 
ELSE 'VEGETABLE'
END) AS FOOD_TYPE
from temptable
```

Comment: are you trying to create a separate temp table of table names 'FRUIT' and 'VEGETABLE' or just a temp table with column FOOD_TYPE to store values 'FRUIT' and 'VEGETABLE'?

Comment: your using multiple tags like sql server and mysql which are you using

Comment: I am trying to create both a new column and a new temp table as a result of the if and then. if a column has 'APPLE' then the FOOD TYPE will be FRUIT and it will create a temp table 'FRUIT'. if column does not have APPLE then the FOOD TYPE is VEGETABLE and it will create with temp table VEGETABLE

Comment: You can use the WITH sentence to create your temp table based on a defined query, and then, use that result as a table.

Example:

WITH Adults AS (SELECT name FROM Persons WHERE age > 18)
SELECT * FROM Adults WHERE name LIKE '%Jhon%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using this query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN food LIKE '%APPLE%' 
            THEN (SELECT 'FRUIT' food_type INTO #FRUIT)
            ELSE (SELECT 'VEGETABLE' food_type INTO #VEGETABLE)
       END
```

Please note that LIKE uses % for wild card before and/or after the keyword contained in the column, if you are to use 'APPLE' or any other value, you should opt to use equal (=) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The question you have asked raises more questions. But that being said, I do not believe this can be achieved in a single statement. The TSQL below (I assume you are using MS SQL Server) will satisfy the question, but the scenarios you presented seems a little odd and may possibly require a rethink.

```
declare @FOOD_TYPE varchar(100);
select top 1 @FOOD_TYPE = 
(CASE 
WHEN food LIKE 'APPLE' THEN 'FRUIT' 
ELSE 'VEGETABLE'
END) 
from @foods

if(@FOOD_TYPE='FRUIT') 
select FOOD_TYPE=@FOOD_TYPE into #FRUIT
else
select FOOD_TYPE=@FOOD_TYPE into #VEGETABLE
```

Comment: it can be achieved in a single statement, instead of the 'FRUIT' or else 'VEGETABLE', substitute it to the select query you have for whatever @food_type value you have

Comment: +1 to the rethink.  Whatever problem the question is aimed at solving should most likely be approached in a different way.